# Gdal substract 1 bit raster gives me hard time

Tags: raster, tiff, gdal, calc

I want to use `gdal_calc` to subtract one file from another. It works, but I get the wrong result all the time no matter what command line i try.
For your understanding I created 3 files.

Picture A:

[image: Picture A]

Picture B:

[image: Picture B]

Picture C:

[image: Result]

As you can see I always get the overlap as result but I need the other part.

Desired Result:

[image: result I want.]

`gdal_calc.py -A pica.tif -B picb.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A-B"`

Change the line to

`gdal_calc.py -A pica.tif -B picb.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="B-A"`

or swap filenames doesn't work? I always get the same result.
I also delete the output file before trying new stuff so thats not the problem that I always look at the same file.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of your black and white pixels? Usually white would be 1 (or 255), and black 0, but that's just a guess. If that's the case, you probably want the inverse, so something like `(1-A)-(1-B)` (if your values are really 1bit).

For testing\debugging, it's a good idea to first convert both input images to an unsigned integer datatype. For example:
`gdal_translate -ot Int32 pica.tif pica_int32.tif`

That would allow negative values in the result, because `gdal_calc` **does  not** convert the data to a new "working datatype" (as gdalwarp can do with `-wt`for example). So that would mean you're doing the calculation in the input datatype (probably Byte?). See the "Note" box at:
https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-type

And if you're subtracting, and the datatype is `Byte`, it probably causes results beyond the valid range of that datatype (like -1). Normal Numpy behavior is to simply "wrap around" (instead of clip etc), so that might cause some surprising results, for example:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1], dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.array([0, 1, 254, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

a - b
```

Results in:

```py
array([  1, 255,   3,   2], dtype=uint8)
```